# flutter, fetching dummy local json

Tags: flutter, dart

i have local dummy `json` and i want to put it on title but the `variables` `forms` does not defined, i don't understand how to call the `forms`

the Json and title both are in different `stateless widget` in same page

> Json

```
  List<dynamic> forms = [
{
      "id": 65,
      "label": "Is this a test drive period or demonstration period?",
      "code": "survey_general",
      "type": "select_box",
      "service_id": 48,
      "client_type": "SURVEY_MITSU",
      "column_order": 1,
      "required": true,
      "options": {
        "step_number": "1",
        "step_label": "General Information",
        "options": []
      },
      "validation": null,
      "requisite": false,
      "multiple": false
    },
]
```

> Title

```
Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(16, 20, 16, 8),
              child: Text(
                'Part 1: ${jsonEncode(forms['options']['step_label'])}',
                style: Constants.textTitle.copyWith(
                  fontSize: 16,
                  fontFamily: 'Nunito',
                ),
              ),
            ),
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not an appropriate approach to access the variables from other Widgets. The **forms** variable is not a local variable in **Title**.

There are two approaches:

1. Put the dummy variable **forms** into the **Title** Widget
2. Create a new class to store your dummy variable

```dart
class Dummy{

static const List<dynamic> forms = [
    {
      "id": 65,
      "label": "Is this a test drive period or demonstration period?",
      "code": "survey_general",
      "type": "select_box",
      "service_id": 48,
      "client_type": "SURVEY_MITSU",
      "column_order": 1,
      "required": true,
      "options": {
        "step_number": "1",
        "step_label": "General Information",
        "options": []
      },
      "validation": null,
      "requisite": false,
      "multiple": false
    },
];
}
```

```dart
Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(16, 20, 16, 8),
              child: Text(
                'Part 1: ${jsonEncode(Dummy.forms['options']['step_label'])}',
                style: Constants.textTitle.copyWith(
                  fontSize: 16,
                  fontFamily: 'Nunito',
                ),
              ),
            ),
```